How to Draw an Ellipse Inside a Square in Two-Point Perspective?
All ellipses drawn with two-point perspective are inside vertical squares.  So how to draw an ellipse inside a square drawn horizontally in two-point perspective?  How can we find the "major" and "minor" lines of the ellipse in such a square? The drawing on the left of the picture I shared below shows the ellipse inside the horizontal square in two-point perspective.  But the "minor" line of the ellipse has no vanishing point.  How that happens?  The picture on the right shows how to easily make an ellipse, they can be drawn quite easily.


Hello, I don't know English.  I am asking the questions using artificial intelligence tools, I had no knowledge about voting.  I apologize.

Search on youtube. There's a tutorial here

Thank you for your video suggestion, but this video helps to draw symmetrical ellipses. I don't know what to do in the situations on the left of the photo I shared.

It would be the same process. No difference.

I made this example using the same technique in the video.

The axles of the ellipse can be seen easily AFTER the ellipse curve has been constructed. But you want to get the axles at first for easier ellipse curve construction. Right?

Thank you very much for your answers, but what I want to explain is different. Look at the first photo of the site I will share the link to below: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3823048/is-the-line-created-by-the-minor-axis-of-an-ellipse-concurrent-to-the-lines-runn

Notice that the ellipses on the left are tilted to the right of the vanishing point. Now; Look to the left of the photo I shared in my question above: the lines coming from the "left vanishing point" are longer than the lines coming from the "right vanishing point". So I think the ellipse to be drawn should not be horizontal like the ellipse you have drawn. It should be inclined depending on the "minor" and "major" lines to be drawn. So how should the "minor" and "major" aspects of the ellipse on the left of the photo be drawn? This was my last question, thank you for all your efforts.

See the answer given by the user named "theophile" to the this question at this link: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/141293/how-to-use-the-minor-axis-to-draw-an-ellipse-in-perspective  For example, the "minor" and "major" axes of the ellipse differ. How can this happen?  The "minor" axes differ from the ellipses you drew.

Thank you so much oneprivate and Billy Kerr.  Now I understand everything.  By the way, we can find the exact solution to this problem with the following method on the "handprint" page: https://www.handprint.com/HP/WCL/perspect5.html#:~:text=projecting%20a%20circle%20without%20a%20plan

Finding at first the minor and major axles of the right ellipse would be useful if one had (and wanted to use) a mechanical ellipse drawing tool which utilizes the axles. Leonardo da Vinci made one for this job. Today the tool is called "ellipse trammel".
Unfortunately the perspective image of a square contains no easy to use hints where the ellipse axles are. We can find easily the tangency points of the ellipse inside the image of the square, but using them to construct the ellipse axles is complex. It can even be impossible with elementary geometry tools. I have only seen some writings which seem to contain geometrical methods to solve the problem in parallel projections, but I have no idea how useful they are for perspective projections of circles inside squares. Maybe Leonardo could understand it.
Computer programs, for ex. Inkscape convert in a second a square and a circle inside it to a perfect perspective image. The function in Inkscape for the job is path effect "Perspective Envelope".
If for some reason I was forced to draw perspective ellipses manually I would use a  method which gives to me a dense enough set of exact points on the ellipse curve. You presented in your own comment such method behind link https://www.handprint.com/HP/WCL/perspect5.html#:~:text=projecting%20a%20circle%20without%20a%20plan.
I want to present one method more. It could be verified easily by using elementary vector algebra. I guess the method behind your link is a streamlined version of the same.

The crossings of the red and blue lines are on the circle curve, because the lines are perpendicular and there's a rectangular triangle which has the diameter of the circle as the hypotenuse. The perpendicularity can be shown easily by thinking the lines as vectors and by calculating the scalar products.
Perspective drawing theory gives easy to use tools to divide straight lines to equal parts in the perspective image. To keep the image compact it's useful to handle each quadrant of the circle independently.
About your comment which wonders user theophile's comment in How to use the minor axis to draw an ellipse in perspective?
Theophile only tells that in rigorous math it's rubbish to assume that in perspective image the ellipse minor axis points to the vanishing point of a cube and presents a 3D line which is perpedicular with the plane of the ellipse. In addition the chord method to estimate the place of the vanishing point of the cube is also rubbish in math. But the said things can still be useful and help to generate pleasant looking (but mathematically wrong) images if they are used in a small enough area in the middle of the cone of vision.

This provides an almost accurate and beautiful method. Thank you again for the information you provided.
